# autocomplete filenames using compgen

Tags: bash, autocomplete, compgen

As part of a larger autocomplete function I'm writing, I want to use compgen to generate a list of files. I read the bash manual entries for `compgen` and `complete`, and from there I assumed that the option `-G "*"` would be the solution. I could not get it to work, though: The list of files in the current directory was shown, regardless of my input, i.e.:

```
$ cmd <Tab>
aa bb cc
$ cmd a<Tab>
aa bb cc
$ cmd aa<Tab>
aa bb cc
```

Therefore, I tried to debug this by using `complete`, which supports the same options as compgen, but I got the same result:

```
$ complete -G "*" cmd
$ cmd a<Tab>
aa bb cc
```

I also tried `complete -o filenames`, but this doesn't work either..

Comment: From what I can find, `-G` is pretty much useless, since it always returns what the glob matches but never filters against what you've typed so far. Anyplace you think you want to use -G, the answer seems to be to use `-A file -X '!<glob>'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer myself: I have to use the `-A action` option:

```
compgen -o filenames -A file ...
complete -o filenames -A file
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can use the default autocompletion for filenames with

```
# at the top of the function to disable default
compopt +o default

# and where you need filename completion, re-enable it and send empty COMPREPLY
compopt -o default
COMPREPLY=()
return 0
```

based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/19062943/1817610