# how to do path completion in bash function

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I read a few articles, but having little to no knowledge of bash script I'm unable to do what I need. like I tried [this SO post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28283/autocomplete-of-filename-in-directory)

I've a function in `.bash_alias` as follows, which simply cd into server folder.

```
html() {
  cd /var/www/html/$1
}
```

So in command `html myapp` it executes `cd /var/www/html/myapp`. This is all fine. I want to take to to Next level.

I want to do `html my<TAB>` so that it auto completes into `html myapp`
Not to hard-code any folder, I want to have the usual default auto completion behavior. If there are multiple folder start with my in the name, list folders maybe as well. Please guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write a completion function (conventionally, we'd name it `_html`).  Then associate that function with the `html` command using the `complete` builtin:

```
_html() {
    local cur prev words cword
    _init_completion || return
   COMPREPLY=($(cd /var/www/html && compgen -o dirnames -- "$cur"))
}

complete -F _html html
```

(Note: `_init_completion` is defined in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`, which I assume you've already sourced - either directly, or via `/etc/bash_completion`)

Comment: OMG, This is Magic. Thank you sense. Could maybe guide me what should I study to know stuff like this? linux home user since a couple years, but no admin experience at all. Would love to start now.

Comment: Just study the man pages and the existing code; look in `/usr/share/bash-completion/` for the completions you have installed, and follow along until you understand how they work.

Comment: @Bsienn `man complete`

Comment: @user234461, ITYM `man bash-builtins`, given that this is Ubuntu.

Comment: @TobySpeight It's usual to overwrite the Ubuntu man pages from a Fedora install after each `apt` update so `man complete` is actually more likely to be useful

Comment: I've never heard of writing Fedora man pages onto an Ubuntu system - that doesn't sound "usual" to me!